# Pingfederate SSO on port 9031

Tags: single-sign-on, pingfederate

Why do SSO providers like Ping Federate run on ports that aren't well-known like 9031.  Does this enhance security? It seems like it just increases connectivity issues in organizations with strict firewall rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just a default semi-random port so that it doesn't clash with existing services on the same machine and is a high port so that the server can run under a non-privileged user account.

For production usage one would typically change it to 443 and/or run a reverse-proxy/loadbalancer in front of the SSO server (on port 443).

Answer (score 0):

Generally security is managed at the perimeter of a network. For deployments I have been involved, port 443 is predominately used for SSO (e.g. PingFederate) at the perimeter.  For the internal network, I have seen two models, mainly (i) change the HTTPS port in PingFederate to 443, or (ii) utilize load balancer port forwarding from 443 to 9031.  I usually see item (i) for Windows deployments and item (ii) for Linux deployments where reserved ports are avoided. There really isn't a true security enhancement for either pattern.

As Hans points out, PingFederate utilizes 9031 as a default so that conflict with other processes on a server are avoided when first deploying the technology.  As the SSO capability matures into an environment, the proper port for the service can be managed.  The default port avoids issues when first installing that can be frustrating to folks new to the technology.